# Nested singleton accessors and variables

Tags: ruby

Was learning method lookup for static methods and variables and i dont understand the attr_reader accessors behaviour, example:

```
class C
  @static = 1
  attr_reader :static

  def objmethod
    p __method__.to_s + " in #{self}"
  end

  def self.static1
    p __method__.to_s + " in #{self}"
  end

  class << self
    @static = 2
    attr_reader :static

    def static2
      p __method__.to_s +  " in #{self}"
    end

    def self.static3
      p __method__.to_s + " in #{self}"
    end

    class << self
      @static = 3
      attr_reader :static

      def static4
        p __method__.to_s + " in #{self}"
      end

      class << self
        @static = 4
        attr_reader :static

        def static5
          p __method__.to_s + " in #{self}"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

So, inspecting methods first:

```
C.static1
C.static2
C.singleton_class.static3
C.singleton_class.static4
C.singleton_class.singleton_class.static5 # good
```

Instance variables from the singleton instance, all good

```
puts "\ninstance_variable_get"
p C.instance_variable_get(:@static)
p C.singleton_class.instance_variable_get(:@static)
p C.singleton_class.singleton_class.instance_variable_get(:@static)
p C.singleton_class.singleton_class.singleton_class.instance_variable_get(:@static) # ok, good
```

Trying to get Instance variables from the singleton instance now using attr_reader accessors

```
puts "\naccessor"
p C.static
p C.singleton_class.static # uhmmm
p C.singleton_class.singleton_class.static # this is not looking good
p C.singleton_class.singleton_class.singleton_class.static # my slave doesnt like this
# undefined method `static' for #<Class:#<Class:#<Class:C>>> (NoMethodError)
```

Why i can't get the last value using accessors? Im missing some aditional knowdledge here.

Comment: Oh, now i realize, the top @static statment is a instance variable for a instanced C, so the C.static call actually goes to the singleton (2nd attr_reader statment), then why does it print 1?

Comment: You need `class << self; attr_reader :static; end` after `def static5; p __method__.to_s + " in #{self}"; end`. Then `C.singleton_class.singleton_class.singleton_class.static #=> 4`.

Comment: The most important thing to understand first, is that Ruby doesn't have static methods or static variables. Ruby has only one kind of methods: instance methods, and it has only 5+3 kinds of variables: local variables, instance variables, class hierarchy variables, constant variables, and global variables, plus thread-local global variables (e.g. `$!`), method-local global variables (e.g. `$1`), and special variables (e.g. `self`).

Comment: Hi guys, i understand, the name static is just for naming only in this case, Thanks Cary, i understand now, the first class << self inside class is just accesing the top class variable, all follows from there, comming from other languages i dont know how this got past me :(, i think the scope played tricks with me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, its a semantic problem with the visual scope.
The first class << self is defining methods for the singleton class of C, so it will share the @static = 1 instance variable.
The rest just follows from there.

Basically, every scope nesting takes the instance variables of where is nesting them.

```
class C
 @instancevariable = 1
 attr_reader :instancevariable # instance method of C.new

 def self.static1 # instance method of C (singleton of C)
   p __method__.to_s + " in #{self}"
 end

 class << self
   @instancevariable = 2  #instance variable of of Class:C (nested singleton)
   attr_reader :instancevariable #instance method of C (singleton of C)

   def static2 #instance method of C (singleton of C)
     p __method__.to_s +  " in #{self}"
   end

   class << self
     attr_reader :instancevariable #instance method of Class:C (singleton of C) this one will see *(instance variable of of Class:C)
   end
 end
end
```